# how to run an asynchronous method in java firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I want to store user's detail into firebase database but I want to first store an image into storageRef and then use the image url that is being returned as my profile image link before final Registration. The issue I am having is that before the image url is returned, the method that stores the full information is also executed there by returning null as my profile image. I am looking for a way  to make the registerStudent method wait until the app successfully uploaded an image before its starts executing so that it can make use of the returned image url as the profile image of the user. This is what I tried

```
private void uploadProfileImage(String regNumber, Uri imageUri, ProgressDialog progressDialog){
        if (imageUri !=null){
            final StorageReference fileRef = profileImageStorageRef
                    .child(regNumber+".jpg");
            StorageTask uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(imageUri);
            uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation() {
                @Override
                public Object then(@NonNull Task task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    return fileRef.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                        myUri = downloadUri.toString();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

private void registerStudent(StudentModel studentModel,ProgressDialog progressDialog){
        HashMap hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("name",studentModel.getName());
        hashMap.put("regNumber",studentModel.getRegNumber());
        hashMap.put("gender",studentModel.getGender());
        hashMap.put("testScore",studentModel.getTestScore());
        hashMap.put("profileImage",myUri);
        hashMap.put("testStatus",studentModel.getTestStatus());

        firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Students")
                .child(studentModel.getRegNumber())
                .updateChildren(hashMap)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(application, "Registration Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(application, "Error Occurred, Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

    }


public void processStudentRegistration(StudentModel studentModel,Uri imageUri, ProgressDialog progressDialog,Activity activity){
        progressDialog.setTitle("Registration Processing....");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait while we are checking your credentials");
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        progressDialog.show();
        firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Registration Number")
                .child(studentModel.getRegNumber())
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()){
                            firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Students").child(studentModel.getRegNumber())
                                    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                            if (snapshot.exists()){
                                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                                showMessage("Error","Student with this Registration Number has Already Registered",activity);
                                            }else {
                                                uploadProfileImage(studentModel.getRegNumber(),imageUri,progressDialog);
                                                registerStudent(studentModel,progressDialog);
                                            }
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                        }
                                    });
                        }else {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            showMessage("Error","You are not qualified to Register for this course",activity);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(application, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

    }
```

Comment: You *really* don't want to block the main thread on network operations like this. Instead, use the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/background-tasks/asynchronous) to learn how asynchronous operations are normally implemented on Android so the app won't crash with an ANR. [The Firebase APIs are all asynchronous for this reason.](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it by making sure that the `registerStudent` is ran after the `registerStudent` is sucessfully completed.
This is how you can achieve it:
Create an interface/callback to handle the image upload completion:

```
public interface ImageUploadCallback {
    void onImageUploadSuccess(String imageUrl);
    void onImageUploadFailure(String errorMessage);
}
```

Then modify the `uploadProfileImage` to this:

```
private void uploadProfileImage(String regNumber, Uri imageUri, ProgressDialog progressDialog, ImageUploadCallback callback) {
    if (imageUri != null) {
        final StorageReference fileRef = profileImageStorageRef.child(regNumber + ".jpg");
        StorageTask<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(imageUri);

        uploadTask.continueWithTask(task -> {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                throw task.getException();
            }
            return fileRef.getDownloadUrl();
        }).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                if (downloadUri != null) {
                    String imageUrl = downloadUri.toString();
                    callback.onImageUploadSuccess(imageUrl); // Image upload success, pass the URL
                } else {
                    callback.onImageUploadFailure("Failed to get image URL");
                }
            } else {
                callback.onImageUploadFailure("Image upload failed");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

At last modify the `processStudentRegistration` to make it handle callBacks like this:

```
public void processStudentRegistration(StudentModel studentModel, Uri imageUri, ProgressDialog progressDialog, Activity activity) {
    // ... (other existing code remains the same)

    uploadProfileImage(studentModel.getRegNumber(), imageUri, progressDialog, new ImageUploadCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onImageUploadSuccess(String imageUrl) {
            studentModel.setProfileImage(imageUrl); // Set the image URL in the student model

            registerStudent(studentModel, progressDialog);
        }

        @Override
        public void onImageUploadFailure(String errorMessage) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            showMessage("Error", errorMessage, activity);
        }
    });
}
```